# Тезаурус и глоссарий

Tags: лексика, значение-слов

В чем разница между тезаурусом и глоссарием?

Answer (score 1):

Тезаурус словарь специальной терминологии. В отличие от толкового словаря, тезаурус позволяет выявить смысл не только с помощью определения, но и посредством соотнесения слова с другими понятиями и их группами, благодаря чему может использоваться для наполнения баз знаний систем искусственного интеллекта.

Comment: бродский, просили привести разницу между **глоссарием** и тезаурусом. А у Вас что? Попробуйте ещё раз.